# Creating a page header for print, my page contains tables

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have an html containing table. Table header repeats on the next page in print mode. I want to add a header that repeat on all pages too. I have tried many ways but all of them did not work. The page header and table header falling together.

I tried finding the perfect solution to my problem and I still can't able to solve.